# Snap Chromium Experiencing Font Issues On Ubuntu

Tags: fonts, snap, chromium

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with Chromium Version 88.0.4324.182 (Official Build) snap (64-bit).

Recently I have been experiencing the issue where the font settings will randomly change on chromium. This can even happen when I am afk.

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

As you can see even when all of the fonts are set correctly the preview space is showing an entirely different font. I would greatly appreciate any help because this font is even missing some characters making browsing somewhat difficult. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I experienced the same issue earlier today, after snap updated chromium to 89.0.4389.72.  As you obverse, changing the font setting doesn't work.

My font problem was resolved by the following steps.

1. Close Chromium.  Chromium also has background processes. Terminate them by `kill` or `pkill`.
2. <del>Refresh font cache by `sudo fc-cache -rfv` and `fc-cache -rfv`</del> [Update: step 2 is unnecessary.]
3. Start Chromium

Comment: I have the exact same problem on the exact same platform, etc as OP. For me, simply closing and re-opening Chromium solves the problem (for a couple days, until it comes back). I wonder what is causing this.